# List all files in c# lib marked as Resource

Tags: c#

Is it possible to list all files which was added to assembly and marked as a resource (not embedded).

I've tried **GetManifestResourceNames** method. It only works with embedded resources. But I need to be that files marked as a resource, in order to access that files by using uri like this *pack://application:,,,/ApplicationName;component/Resources/logo.png*

thanks

Comment: What do you mean? An embedded RESX file that in addition has resources?

Comment: no, I meant separate files saved in some folder and marked as Resource. Without adding these files to resx file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ApplicationName;component/Resources/logo.png", UriKind.Absolute))
```

**[EDIT]**

And you can list all of them by calling this method:

```
public static string[] GetResourceNames()
{
    var asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    string resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
    using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resName))
    using (var reader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(stream))
    {
        return reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(entry => (string)entry.Key).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I know, but I need to check if this file exists previously

Comment: Yes, this is what I was searching for. Thanks Alex